# TypeError when trying to get the last 5 objects from a JSON

Tags: python, json, request, typeerror

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36"}

url = f'https://.......'
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers).json()
graphs = response['graphPoints']
soma = sum(abs(d["value"]) for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])

print(soma)
```

```
soma = sum(d["value"] for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

How can I solve this `TypeError`?

**Note:** In other response from this same API, this error does not appear, but I couldn't find what sets it apart and what is creating such a problem..

**Note 2:** I honestly found other questions here in the community about this same typified error, but I couldn't understand how to solve them in my specific case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need read graphPoints twice, replace

```
soma = sum(d["value"] for d in graphs["graphPoints"][-5:])
```

with

```
soma = sum(d["value"] for d in graphs[-5:])
```

Comment: Oh @mapr yes, I ended up trying to call a path that was already done, thanks for showing me this flaw!